# Cypress cancelling xhr request on chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, cypress

I am trying to launch a URL using the CYPRESS tool. The issue here is when I try to launch the URL there are some XHR request which is getting canceled by cypress runner due to which the correct page is not getting loaded.

Please note that the issue is only happening on chrome browser and works fine on firefox

Also, these XHR request load just after the URL is launched ad takes very less time to respond. Not sure about what the exact issue is.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem at my end.

Setting and using `requestTimeout` and `responseTimeout` in your configuration file with specific values should solve the problem.

Ref : https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Timeouts

Comment: This i already tried but the issue is not with the time as manually in no time the API is getting the request. also, it's not failure but it starts canceling the request.